# How to disable Razor syntax in Razor scope?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to disable Razor syntax inside Razor's scope just for text written to that HTML

Here's menu separator that I'd want to display only if condition (expr) is satisfied

```
@if (expr)
{
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
}
```

throws

```
Invalid expression term '}'
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                                                          ^
; expected
```

Due to that '|'

But I'd want to display that "string" as pure HTML.

Comment: Try with `<text>...</text>` element: `<text><a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> | </text>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<text>` syntax](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax) to render HTML tags and literal characters inside Razor block:

```
@if (expr)
{
    <text>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
    </text>
}
```

Razor will treat all elements wrapped inside `<text>` element as HTML content to render  in view page instead of server-side code which adheres C# language syntax rules.